# Node js Error: Cannot find module './lib/socket.io'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I had my server working with an earlier version of node.js, npm, and socket.io but after updating I started getting issues with socket.io:

```
    Error: Cannot find module './lib/socket.io'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:333:15)
    at Function._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/index.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:309:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

i have installed socket.io module with command npm

```
install socket.io
```

which placed socket.io under node_modules in my project. I found it strange at first that the error message was saying "./lib/socket.io" but when I looked into it I found that project/node_modules/socket.io/index.js is requiring socket.io like so:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/socket.io');
```

this line giving me error Error: Cannot find module './lib/socket.io'

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to reinstall the `socket.io` module also can you dump the line where you require socket.io ?

Comment: yes Phoenix i have re install socket.io many times

receiving same error

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm cache clean` I had a similar problem, and I found this tip here: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2012/02/27/my-tale-of-npm-woe-when-all-else-fails-clear-you-cache/