# Node.js, (AWS EC2 Instance, MongoDB,) Error: Cannot find module './lib/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am trying to reproduce a node.js server on an AWS EC2 instance. I have already successfully created a basic hello world page, and now have a login/authentication page that I would like to display. The webpage uses a MongoDB Database hosted on the localhost (port 80), and when I run the web page on my laptop it works fine. The JavaScript file is called `server.js`. From the terminal I perform the following (using Mac OS X):

```
$ cd /path/etc/relevantdirectory/
$ nohup sudo mongod & 
$ nohup sudo node server.js
```

Then using Chrome I can access the homepage fine from `localhost`.

However, when I try to perform the identical process from inside a AWS EC2 instance (running on Amazon Linux) I get the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXXX ABC]$ sudo node server.js 

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './lib/'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/XXXXXXXX/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXXX ABC]$
```

I have the following Node.js packages installed:

```
    bcrypt-nodejs  express          morgan                  passport-local
    body-parser    express-session  node-core-module-names  passport-twitter
    connect-flash  forever          nodemon                 path
    cookie-parser  inherits         passport                serve-favicon
    debug          method-override  passport-facebook
    ejs            mongoose         passport-google-oauth
```

I have followed solutions from the following links:

[Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323982/error-cannot-find-module-lib-cli)

[Node.js Error: Cannot find module express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162308/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-express)

[Node js Error: Cannot find module './lib/socket.io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806547/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-lib-socket-io)

but nothing seems to be resolving the issue.

I am fairly new to Node.js and this is my first webpage that I am trying to make/host, so any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Most intrigued by why you would think you need to or even want to run your app as root ( suggest some reading on that topic ), but really have you even tried running `npm list` on the "installed" instance? My money is on nothing is actually installed.

Comment: Thanks @Blakes Seven , I found uninstalling and re-installing my `node modules` fixed the issue, and I have since removed the `sudo` (I had been using a port that required elevated privileges and had been using `sudo` to bypass the issues this raised).